# File Save functionality in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file

I am looking for file saving ( in my local file system) functionality in Angular. I already gone through following modules.

[Angular-file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver)

But it asked for confirmation before saving file.

I want my file to saved automatically in my local folder ( C:\MyApplication\contents)

```
FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([data], { type: "video/mp4" }), 'C:\MyApplication\contents\myvideo.mp4');
```

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 9):

I think the best way is to handle it yourself.

Create a blob from your data.

```
myBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(myData)], {type: "octet/stream"});
```

Now create `<a>` element in the memory and click on it.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);;
link.click();
```